# How does $2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin2\theta$ help with $ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{1-r^2}(r^2\cos^2\theta)(r^2\sin^2\theta)\,r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The integral

$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-r^2} (r^2\cos^2\theta)(r^2\sin^2\theta)\,r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta
$$

The professor says that using the trig identity $$2\sin\theta\cos\theta=\sin(2\theta)$$ will help with integrating. I figured out a messier way to integrate this, but I don't understand how I can implement this trig identity in order to integrate this.

Comment: Calculating aside $\int_0^1r^5(1-r^2)dr,$ you are left with the computation of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(2\theta)}4d\theta.$

Comment: Then you can use $\frac14\sin^22\theta=\frac18(1-\cos4\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating aside $\int_0^1r^5(1-r^2)dr,$ you are left with the computation of $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(2\theta)}4d\theta,$ which you can easily perform, using
$\sin^2(2\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(4\theta)}2.$

Comment: I am confused on how you got to that end product. I don't understand how integrating the first two bounds led to that result.

Comment: $\iiint_{\theta\in I,(r,z)\in T}f(r,z)g(\theta)dzdrd\theta=\left(\iint_Tf(r,z)dzdr\right)\left(\int_Ig(\theta)d\theta\right).$ Is that what you were missing, or is it something else?

Comment: I figured out how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}sin^2(2\theta)=\frac{1}{8}[1-cos(4\theta)]$.

The integral of $\frac{1}{8}[1-cos(4\theta)]$ is much easier to be calculated.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Divide the integral by $1/4$ to compensate for the two you will include inside the squared trigonometric term $(2cos(\theta)sin(\theta))^2$ you will get the following integrand:

$$\frac{1}{8}r^5sin^2(\theta)$$

I am going to ignore the bounds for now, let's focus on the integrand:

Clearly,
$$cos^2(\theta)sin^2(\theta)=(cos(\theta)sin(\theta))^2=1(cos(\theta)sin(\theta))^2=\frac{4}{4}(cos(\theta)sin(\theta))^2=\frac{1}{4}(2cos(\theta)sin(\theta))^2=\text{Here comes the Identity: }\frac{1}{4}(sin(2\theta))^2$$

As for why we get $\frac{1}{8}$, that's to compensate for $2\theta$. Change of variable: $2\theta=u$ then $2d\theta=du$ so $d\theta=\frac{du}{2}$. Actually, the bound will have to change for $u$: $0 \to 4\pi$.

Comment: Why would I have to divide the integral by 1/4? Based on what you have written, can I not simply state $\cos^2θsin^2θ$ as $(cosθsinθ)^2$ giving me sin(θ)?

Comment: Actually, I understand the 1/4 to compensate for the two but how did 1/4 get squared to result in 1/8?

Comment: Furthermore, how can I add a 2 to my integral in order to use the trig identity? I'm not following how we can just add the number 2 to our integrand to fit the trig identity.

Comment: @user1245776 Explanations added, feel free to look again.

Comment: Oh my goodness. This makes so much more sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1245776 Welcome!